# Get number of workers in nUnit

Tags: c#, .net, testing, nunit

I need to get current number of nUnit workers. I also pass this in command line.

How can I get values which is passed in CLI?

I run my tests through

```
dotnet test -- NUnit.NumberOfTestWorkers=2
```

command and I need to get the number of workers. I have tried to get this values using

```
string[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

but I'm getting different arguments:

```
2022-03-14 16:00:49 INFO - --port
2022-03-14 16:00:49 INFO - 51238
2022-03-14 16:00:49 INFO - --endpoint
2022-03-14 16:00:49 INFO - 127.0.0.1:051238
2022-03-14 16:00:49 INFO - --role
2022-03-14 16:00:49 INFO - client
2022-03-14 16:00:49 INFO - --parentprocessid
2022-03-14 16:00:49 INFO - 21628
2022-03-14 16:00:49 INFO - --telemetryoptedin
2022-03-14 16:00:49 INFO - false
```

Comment: 1. this is definitly not what `arguments` returns, but some log-file which may or may not be relevant here - we don't know. 2. Why do you need to know that at all? What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: 1. This is just printed in a foreach cycle values of arguments. 2. I have a web tests for multiple users. These users are stored in a thread safe collection. My tests run in parallel for each user. I want to check that amount of workers passed in command line is less or equal than amount of users in my collection.